# Custom palette import in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, color-palette

I'm trying to import custom diverging palette using [reference guide](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-custom-color-palettes) to Tableau 9.1. Here is my Preferences.tps file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<workbook>
 <preferences>
  <color-palette name=“Red-Blue-Green Diverging2“ type="ordered-diverging" >
 <color>#009900</color>
 <color>#0000CD</color>
 <color>#CC0000</color>
 </color-palette>
 </preferences>
</workbook>
```

After doing this and restarting Tableau I can't find the palette in the list. Is there anythyng I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Have you saved it in the tableau repository?

Answer (score 1):

You're using curly, non-ASCII quotation marks to quote `name=“Red-Blue-Green Diverging2“`. Instead, use `"`.

```
<color-palette name="Red-Blue-Green Diverging2" type="ordered-diverging" >
```